# Mi login en MYSQLI ingresa con cualquier contraseña

Tags: php, mysqli, login

Primero que nada agradecerles a todos con su ayuda para pasar mi login a Mysqli, ahora el tema es que este ingresa con cualquier contraseña, creo que debe ser algun error en la consulta, les dejo el codigo y me dicen que tal. Gracias!!

```
 $sentencia = $con->prepare("SELECT id, nombre, skin, nivel, adminlvl FROM cuenta WHERE nombre=? OR email=? AND pass=? ");  
                    $sentencia->bind_param("sss", $nombre_str, $email_str, $pass_str);  
                    $sentencia->execute(); 
                    $sentencia->store_result();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema puede ser la precedencia de los operadores lógicos, en tu caso estas usando las sentencias `OR` y `AND`, en **MySQL** la precedencia de los operadores es la siguiente de mayor a menor:

```
INTERVAL
BINARY, COLLATE
!
- (unary minus), ~ (unary bit inversion)
^
*, /, DIV, %, MOD
-, +
<<, >>
&
|
= (comparison), <=>, >=, >, <=, <, <>, !=, IS, LIKE, REGEXP, IN
BETWEEN, CASE, WHEN, THEN, ELSE
NOT
AND, &&
XOR
OR, ||
= (assignment), :=
```

En este caso primero se evaluara el AND por lo que si el nombre o email son correctos la sentencia OR será válida, para corregir esto deberías usar paréntesis

```
SELECT id, nombre, skin, nivel, adminlvl FROM cuenta WHERE (nombre=? OR email=?) AND pass=?
```

Para más información de la precedencia de operadores en MySQL revisa:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/operator-precedence.html

Comment: Muchas gracias, era simplemente eso :)

Comment: @SantiagoD'Antuoni cual era simplemento eso? como lo solucionaste?

Comment: Si, lo solucione era que tenia que poner parentesis para que el sql respetara el orden.